# mySQL select IN range

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to define a range for the IN part of the query, something like this

```
SELECT job FROM mytable WHERE id IN (10..15);
```

Instead of

```
SELECT job FROM mytable WHERE id IN (10,11,12,13,14,15);
```

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You can't, but you can use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT job FROM mytable WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```

Note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, and will include items with both id 10 and 15.

If you do not want inclusion, you'll have to fall back to using the `>` and `<` operators.

```
SELECT job FROM mytable WHERE id > 10 AND id < 15
```

Comment: what should I do if I want to query the first 5 items in my table? for example the ids are 1,2,5,6,7,8. In this case above approach will return just 1,2,5.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I would suggest writing a new question with more details.

Comment: @soroosh: you could do it with a subquery that returns the 5th value.

Answer (score 7):

To select data in numerical range you can use `BETWEEN` which is inclusive.

```
SELECT JOB FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID BETWEEN 10 AND 15;
```

Comment: What's the difference to ESG's answer?

Comment: Spammy duplicate except this one is bad practice with putting the column and table in upper-case. Column names are case-insensitive so that's okay (as in, wont produce an error), but table names are case-sensitive in most Unix systems. (But on Windows table-name is also case-insensitive so this query would succeed there)... All in all it's a good plan to not confuse people with unnecessary playing with upper-case. How this gets upvoted after ESG's answer is beyond me.