# SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col1, Col2 BETWEEN a AND b

Tags: mysql

I have a table of different packages like this:

```
term package1 package2 package3
1yr     1000     2000     3000
2yr     1800     3800     5800
3yr     2500     5500     7500
```

Now I want to select all rows where value is between a and b.

I tried using this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE package1, package2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
```

Comment: You need 2 conditions combined with `AND`: `(package1 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000) AND (package2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000)`

Comment: I was thinking `OR`... but... what's a `Raw`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want rows where any of the values are between 1000 and 5000, you need to test each of them and combine with `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE package1 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
OR package2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
OR package3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
```

If you want rows where *all* the values are in the range, change `OR` to `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can achieve this. Use between or > and < symbols [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586035/mysql-select-in-range)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you'll be stuck doing multiple where statements like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE (package1 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000) OR
(package2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000) OR
package3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
```

Or if you need all the packages year to be within those values for that row:

```sql
WHERE (package1 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000) AND
(package2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000) AND
package3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

your query should be against each column combined with and

```
  SELECT * FROM Products 
 WHERE (package1 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000) 
 And (package2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000) 
 And (package3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000);
```