# Big SQL Select Query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have table `lids` with under 430k entries.
How can I do `SELECT` query faster, optimized because now this query working under 5-7 minutes.
Heard something about Eloquent chunk in Laravel, but need clear PHP solution or with `DB` object.
Maybe with 'for' construction to process 100-1000 entries at a time, smthng like this.

Tried to do 'for' construction, but don't know how to do this optimized.

Be gentle with me pls :)

Want to know your opinion.

How can i upgrade it?

UPD: Did something like this

```
$count = $db->doQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM `lids`"); // db - my custom object with Database connection
$count = $count[0]['count(*)'];
$hundreds = $count / 100; // get 'for' counts

$start = 43; // id index starts from 43 in the table
$end = 142;

for ($index = 1; $index < $hundreds; $index++) {

    $leads = [];
    $leads = $db->doQuery("SELECT * FROM `lids` WHERE `id` BETWEEN " . $start . " AND " . $end . "");

    // var_dump($leads);
    // die();

    if (empty($leads)) {
        $start += 100;
        $end += 100;
        continue;
    }

    $uniques = [];

    foreach ($leads as $lead) {
        if (empty($lead['json_vars'])) continue;

        $vars = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $lead['json_vars']); // hot fix for charset, from DB comes string in utf8mb4
        $json = json_decode($vars, true);

        if (!isset($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE']) || !str_contains($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'], '_fbc')) continue;

        $lead['json_vars'] = $json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'];

        // check for unique values
        if (!isset($uniques[$lead['id']]) || $uniques[$lead['id']]['phone'] != $lead['phone']) {
            $uniques[$lead['id']] = $lead;
        }

    }

    foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
        $lid = Lid::create($unique);
    }

    $start += 100;
    $end += 100;

    // here i get residue of entries
    if ($hundreds - $index < 1) {
        $leads = $db->doQuery("SELECT * FROM `lids` WHERE `id` IN(" . ($count - $hundreds * 100) . ", " . $count . ") AND WHERE ");
 
        foreach ($leads as $lead) {
            $json = json_decode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $lead['json_vars']), true);
            if (!str_contains($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'], '_fbc')) continue;
            $lead['json_vars'] = $json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'];
            $lid = Lid::create($lead);
        }
    }

}
```

Upd2:

```
$db = new Database();
$counter = 0;

$scriptStart = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime('now'));

$lastRemote = $db->lastId('lids');

$lastInner = Lid::all(['id'])->last();
$lastInner = $lastInner->id;

$count = $lastRemote - $lastInner;

if ($count < 0) {

    echo 'no new objects, canceled';
    return false;
}

$start = $lastInner + 1;
$end = $lastRemote;
$fewEntries = false;

if ($count < 500) {

    $fewEntries = true;
    $index = $lastInner;
    $hundreds = $lastRemote;
} else {

    $index = 1;
    $hundreds = $count / 100;
    $end = $start + 99;
}

if ($fewEntries) {

    $leads = $db->itemsBetween('lids', 'id', [$start, $end]);

    $uniques = [];

    foreach ($leads as $lead) {

        if (empty($lead['json_vars'])) continue;

        $vars = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $lead['json_vars']);
        $json = json_decode($vars, true);

        if (!isset($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE']) || !str_contains($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'], '_fbc')) continue;

        $lead['json_vars'] = $json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'];

        if (
            !isset($uniques[$lead['id']]) ||
            $uniques[$lead['id']]['phone'] != $lead['phone'] &&
            $uniques[$lead['id']]['ip'] != $lead['ip'] &&
            $uniques[$lead['id']]['request_link'] != $lead['request_link']
        ) {
            $uniques[$lead['id']] = $lead;
        }
    }

    foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
        $lid = Lid::create($unique);
        $counter++;
    }
} else {

    for ($index; $index < $hundreds; $index++) {

        $leads = [];
        $leads = $db->itemsBetween('lids', 'id', [$start, $end]);

        // var_dump($leads);
        // die();

        $uniques = [];

        foreach ($leads as $lead) {

            if (empty($lead['json_vars'])) continue;

            $vars = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $lead['json_vars']);
            $json = json_decode($vars, true);

            if (!isset($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE']) || !str_contains($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'], '_fbc')) continue;

            $lead['json_vars'] = $json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'];

            if (
                !isset($uniques[$lead['id']]) ||
                $uniques[$lead['id']]['phone'] != $lead['phone'] &&
                $uniques[$lead['id']]['ip'] != $lead['ip'] &&
                $uniques[$lead['id']]['request_link'] != $lead['request_link']
            ) {
                $uniques[$lead['id']] = $lead;
            }
        }

        foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
            $lid = Lid::create($unique);
            $counter++;
        }

        $start += 100;
        $end += 100;
    }
}

$scriptEnd = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime('now'));

echo 'added in table: ' . $counter . PHP_EOL;
echo 'started at: ' . $scriptStart . PHP_EOL;
echo 'ended at: ' . $scriptEnd . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to iterate over all  entries? Or are you looking for a specific one?

Comment: I want to iterate all entries

Comment: And want to do cron task faster :)

Comment: Have a look at the [cursor documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#cursors), if that doesn't help, we're going to need some code to help you

Comment: @AlexSergeev Have you indexed the columns in that particular table? [Create index](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/creating-table-advance/create-index.php)

Comment: Just as a general tip, it can be good practice to process large datasets in batches rather than a single job all at once.

Doing so will reduce the server load and make sure that if an error occurs you can just redo the batch that failed rather than all of them again at once.

This isn't always possible, as I appreciate sometimes it needs to have an all or nothing approach, but if it fits with your needs then thats another avenue to explore.

The cursor recommendation by @CerebralFart is a good idea to look into too.

Comment: I have two DB connections, first DB inside the Laravel project in .env file, second DB is remote, in another server.
From second DB i take entries and after iteration put them in Laravel DB using Eloquent models.

Comment: and i did something like this to take entries from remote DB, updated task description

Comment: @OliverScase yep, i'm trying to process datasets in batches but i don't understand what kind of loops or constructions i need to realize for optimized and correct solution :(

Like a kind of solution wrote up at description.
Is the approach correct?

Comment: @CerebralFart need your help guys, hint about cursors was really nice, but need solution like in description, to process 100 or 1,000 entries step by step

Comment: @AlexSergeev your SQL where clause is not right for your idea. When you use `in (43, 143)`  it will return max 2 elements. You either want to user BETWEEN or > and <  in your where clause. See the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586069/5841606) - as an alternative your could (if the database is not changed in between) work with Limit (to limit the rows) and offset (to walk through your table).

Comment: @Uwe, yeah, thanks for this, i just had this problem, fix with `BETWEEN * AND *`

Comment: well, i wrote something wrong or that solution is the best?

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE lids`.  Please show us the `SELECT(s)` _after_ it has been constructed by PHP.

Comment: What is the _real_ problem and goal??  It looks like a character set problem.  There may be a way to fix it without iterating over the rows one by one!

Comment: @RickJames `json_vars` row contain big json object.  Because `strstr` or `substr` func not valid solution in this situation, tranform to PHP Array them one by one. Then need to find `HTTP_COOKIE` property and then needed cookie. Real problem was speed of execution, it's cron task, goal was also speed of this script.
I alredy solved my problem with taking only new rows from DB table, check this out in description :)

Comment: @AlexSergeev - As you found out, "fetching a row" is the most costly part of an operation.  Second might be parsing the JSON.  So, fewer rows --> faster.  (Assuming adequate indexing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem with optimization of my trash code XD

```
$db = new Database();
$counter = 0;

$scriptStart = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime('now'));

$lastRemote = $db->lastId('lids');

$lastInner = Lid::all(['id'])->last();
$lastInner = $lastInner->id;

$count = $lastRemote - $lastInner;

if ($count < 0) {

    echo 'no new objects, canceled';
    return false;
}

$start = $lastInner + 1;
$end = $lastRemote;
$fewEntries = false;

if ($count < 500) {

    $fewEntries = true;
    $index = $lastInner;
    $hundreds = $lastRemote;
} else {

    $index = 1;
    $hundreds = $count / 100;
    $end = $start + 99;
}

if ($fewEntries) {

    $leads = $db->itemsBetween('lids', 'id', [$start, $end]);

    $uniques = [];

    foreach ($leads as $lead) {

        if (empty($lead['json_vars'])) continue;

        $vars = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $lead['json_vars']);
        $json = json_decode($vars, true);

        if (!isset($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE']) || !str_contains($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'], '_fbc')) continue;

        $lead['json_vars'] = $json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'];

        if (
            !isset($uniques[$lead['id']]) ||
            $uniques[$lead['id']]['phone'] != $lead['phone'] &&
            $uniques[$lead['id']]['ip'] != $lead['ip'] &&
            $uniques[$lead['id']]['request_link'] != $lead['request_link']
        ) {
            $uniques[$lead['id']] = $lead;
        }
    }

    foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
        $lid = Lid::create($unique);
        $counter++;
    }
} else {

    for ($index; $index < $hundreds; $index++) {

        $leads = [];
        $leads = $db->itemsBetween('lids', 'id', [$start, $end]);

        // var_dump($leads);
        // die();

        $uniques = [];

        foreach ($leads as $lead) {

            if (empty($lead['json_vars'])) continue;

            $vars = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $lead['json_vars']);
            $json = json_decode($vars, true);

            if (!isset($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE']) || !str_contains($json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'], '_fbc')) continue;

            $lead['json_vars'] = $json['ser']['HTTP_COOKIE'];

            if (
                !isset($uniques[$lead['id']]) ||
                $uniques[$lead['id']]['phone'] != $lead['phone'] &&
                $uniques[$lead['id']]['ip'] != $lead['ip'] &&
                $uniques[$lead['id']]['request_link'] != $lead['request_link']
            ) {
                $uniques[$lead['id']] = $lead;
            }
        }

        foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
            $lid = Lid::create($unique);
            $counter++;
        }

        $start += 100;
        $end += 100;
    }
}

$scriptEnd = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime('now'));

echo 'added in table: ' . $counter . PHP_EOL;
echo 'started at: ' . $scriptStart . PHP_EOL;
echo 'ended at: ' . $scriptEnd . PHP_EOL;
```